# How do I place redstone with a command block?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing Minecraft on the Nintendo Switch and I am trying to place redstone with a command block and I keep getting this message.

Command:

```
/setblock 716 14.5 -247 Redstone
```

Error message:

```
Syntax error: unexpected "Redstone":" at 14.5-247 >> Redstone <<"
```

Comment: It would be clearer if you posted the error message you got and your command as text, rather than a blurry photo of your screen.

Comment: the command is /setblock 716 14.5 -247 Redstone and the error code is Syntax error: unexpected "Redstone":" at 14.5-247 >> Redstone <<"

Answer (score 3):

Here are the problems with your command:

- `Redstone` is not a valid block ID. The correct ID is `redstone_wire`.
- Decimals don't matter in your command. Using `/setblock 716 14.5 -247 redstone_wire` is the same as writing `/setblock 716 14 -247 redstone`. The command rounds your number down.

Answer (score 0):

The "Redstone" needs to be lowercase.
I don't remember if it's not "redstone" do "redstone_dust"

Comment: nether of those worked

Comment: Do you mean to comment on the other answer by ExpertCoder14? Please move your comment there and click the check mark if you liked my answer.